# Acumatica GI - filter by list of conditions

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to limit a simple GI by a list of stock item numbers, that is currently 30 but soon can grow to 50-60.
I want to avoid having to just use or-or-or in brackets 50+ times.
I use something similar to this elsewhere
ARPASTSOLN.ITEMNUM in ["01106001353", "01106001980", "01110001000", "01110001353", "01110001980", "01111001000", "01111001353"]
and like this in Acumatica =([ARTran.InventoryID] in ('01169001980', '02233001000')) but even though its in the editor, Acumatica comes back:  Unsupported formula operator 'In.'
I'm not tied this this way, so any suggestions on how to filter by a list would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this, at least without customization. Have you considered possibly filtering by a class or attribute value or something instead?

Comment: If you can put these in their own item class, you could filter on item class.  If you need to mark the items in a completely independent way, just add a new custom field.  If you put the field on InventoryItem and add to the Stocked Items screen, you could have end-user maintenance of the field to include or exclude in your GI.  Then just add that field to your GI.  For example, add a bool field called UsrXXIncludeInMyGI.  Set it to True on all desired items. Then add InventoryItemExt.UsrXXIncludeInMyGI to the GI filtering on where it only equals True.

Comment: @BrianStevens - An attribute would be equally simple and require no code.

Comment: @Deetz - agreed, but it depends on the use case.  If you add as an attribute of Item Class, then anyone with access to the attribute would be able to manipulate it.  Also, the attribute would need to be added for every Item Class that could need to have it set.  Since the use case is unspecified, it is very possible that is a better approach.  My perspective is to setup the field and then have access rights of that field limited to only those roles that should maintain it.  I personally don't use the other implementation of attributes as a custom field, so I can't weigh in on that approach.

Comment: Ha, fair enough :)